# Error 404--Not Found aplicação Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Estou obtendo o erro

> Error 404--Not Found: The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI

ao tentar acessar qualquer `url` da minha aplicação, o estranho é que a página `index.jsp` funciona normalmente, inclusive carregando os *resources* que defino no `springmv-servlet.xml`.

**Estrutura do projeto:**

```
+ siebelutilities
+-- WebContent/
  +-- META-INF/
  +-- resources/
  +-- WEB-INF/
    +-- jsp/
     +-- lib/
     +-- springmvc-servlet.xml
     +-- tiles.xml
     +-- web.xml
     +-- weblogic.xml
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>siebelutilities</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.tiles</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eduardo.siebutil.service" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Estou o `@RequestMapping` assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/create")
public ModelAndView create() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/account/create");

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Colocando um debug na linha do ModelAndView model chega a passar ou não? Minha dúvida é se não está conseguindo encontrar o arquivo JSP ou o método, porque pelo erro esta dando a entender que ele não está encontrando um arquivo. O servidor não encontrou nada com a URL que foi passada. Acredito que dentro do construtor do ModelAndView você precisa passar o arquivo correspondente.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian ele nem captura o breakpoint, eu utilizo essa configuração de servlet pra outros projetos Spring e funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, porém de maneira estranha, detectei um `import` de uma lib que eu não possuía no meu `classpath` e o eclipse não me acusava esse erro (`The import xxx cannot be resolved`). Ao fazer uma alteração no `pom.xml` fiz um update do projeto maven e aí foi detectado, então fiz um **Project > Clean** e minhas páginas estão sendo chamadas.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu retorno, será que não tem uma configuração no seu Eclipse que esta ignorando esse erro?

Comment: A princípio eu não estou enxergando nada, @GiancarloGiulian. Pensei que eu tinha desativado a Validação do eclipse para esse projeto mas ela está ativada, por isso não descarto a ideia de que o problema possa ser outro que acabou sendo resolvido indiretamente.